# MT4 installer stuck at download phase

Tags: wine, winetricks

I'm using Wine for Metatrader 4 platform on 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04. When I run the exe installer, the download window gets stuck.

[image]

I've already typed `winetricks winhttp` in the terminal and downloaded the necessary exe files.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You might not like my answer but the easiest way is to first install the software on a windows box,  then copy the folder metatrader to your linux box. This is how I personally do it.

If you need more details just let me know.

Martin